# How to disable systemcalls in ftp environment with vsftpd?

Tags: security, ftp, chroot, vsftpd, jail

I've set up a vsftpd server with local users jailed within their home directories.
Anyhow if I connect through a ftp client I can execute systemcalls with the "!" command.
How can I configure vsftpd to deny those calls?

```
ftp> ! cat /etc/shadow
... Working! Contents of /etc/shadow will be visible ...
```

Update:

The problem was that the vsftpd server was running with root rights and thus being able to read the shadows file.

But the question is still there:

How can I disable those systemcalls in general?

Comment: `!` commands are executed by the ftp client, in the client system. The server can't block them because it never sees them. In fact you can do a `!` command when you're not connected to any server at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands that start with an exclamation mark <kbd>!</kbd> escape the FTP **client** and are executed locally with the rights of your local user.  The **don't  run on the server**, actually they won't even reach the server, so there is nothing for vsftpd to block.

Comment: So it only worked cause I was connected to localhost to test the ftp server... Thanks!